# Extraction of year issue in covid-19 dataset from JHU

Tags: r

I'm trying to follow the worked out exercise given at [COVID-19 Data Analysis with R - Worldwide by Yanchang Zhao](https://78462f86-a-e2d7344e-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/rdatamining.com/www/docs/Coronavirus-data-analysis-world.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cquiKfCKS7vYOh7nBh76B1FqYaZ2eKPgNr8JuyWdBREtMxfZJWvMpXiy2UsBzHXOJ-czopW8N_6sVzULeDwcQQzUKxN3h32jXKucTdX-V1k8o_LIlQTiqFZSkLIqLQXWHR2hpLglrGiPuPgt-VReFroMpCb6GQr3XDya07GR_DQGT2gjPDptEgS_jnxOmNuw4MPaRJNhJkoCPmFf2XUe6-H2mjSQpgtpm1T06u4xyQYeZ50RuU%3D&attredirects=1) which is a covid-19 related data analysis performed in R.

and during the step of loading data, I find an issue with the date format where it is suppose to print the date range in the data set as

"2020-01-22" "2020-06-15"

but when I attempt, it gives me

"2002-10-10" "2020-10-09"

as I'm strictly following the exercise script, I am confused with the origin of time being "2002" instead of "2020". Did anyone in the community has experience such issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide your code? You say you're following a tutorial, but if you are writing the code, you could have a typo.

Comment: Hi @Zachucks, my code is available at 

https://github.com/madhuranga84/R-learning/blob/main/covid-study.R

Thank you!